# Manually change bar width using ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

I've been trying to change the bars width and I'm using geom_bar (width) but it does not change the bars width, I need to make them more narrow

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
color_table <- tibble(
  Land_cover = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  Color = c("yellow", "darkgreen", "blue4", "maroon3")
)

df <- data.frame(
  name=c("FM_BICEP","FM_NR","FM_TRICEP","FM_H_GRASP1","FM_CS_SPE","FM_MOS_SFL","FM_H_GRASP3*","FM_FS_RET","FM_W_SE3","FM_FS_ABD*","FM_MOS_SAB") ,  
  value=c(1.7,1.8,1.8,22.0,26.8,27.4,27.9,31.8,33.4,35.8,35.8),
  group=c("A","A","A","C","D","A","C","A","B","A","A")
)

df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = df$name)
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = color_table$Land_cover)

# Barplot
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=value,fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=group))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
   scale_fill_manual(values = color_table$Color) + geom_col(width = 0.4)
```

Comment: Remove `geom_col(width = 0.4)` (except you have any reason to add a duplicated col layer) and move `width = 0.4` to the geom_bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `geom_col()` as you use both `x` and `y` axis. It's the same as `geom_bar(scale = "identity")`.

Also, to `width` work, I moved it to inside the `geom_bar()` function.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
color_table <- tibble(
  Land_cover = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  Color = c("yellow", "darkgreen", "blue4", "maroon3")
)

df <- data.frame(
  name=c("FM_BICEP","FM_NR","FM_TRICEP","FM_H_GRASP1","FM_CS_SPE","FM_MOS_SFL","FM_H_GRASP3*","FM_FS_RET","FM_W_SE3","FM_FS_ABD*","FM_MOS_SAB") ,  
  value=c(1.7,1.8,1.8,22.0,26.8,27.4,27.9,31.8,33.4,35.8,35.8),
  group=c("A","A","A","C","D","A","C","A","B","A","A")
)

df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = df$name)
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = color_table$Land_cover)

# Barplot
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=value,fill = group)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=group),
           width = 0.4)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_table$Color)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>